# vue component can not get this.$router from vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Vue component can not get this.$router, but get this.$route in App component, what could be wrong?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'

import FeedView from './views/FeedView.vue'
import LoginView from './views/LoginView.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.config.devtools = true

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: __dirname,
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: FeedView },
    { path: '/login', component: LoginView },
  ]
})

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

[capture image of vue-devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P81MN.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearly explained in vue-router docs: https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html

> The route object can be found in multiple places:
>   Inside components as this.$route
>   Inside $route watcher callbacks
>   As the return value of calling router.match(location)

If you want to use e.g. `router.push()`, based on your code, you definitely should be able to use `this.$router.push()`